# Запутался в переопределениях методов java

Tags: java, наследование, переопределение

Разрабатываю приложение на [android](/questions/tagged/android) - ключевая задача: работа с базой данных.

Есть абстрактный класс `Catalog` справочник, от него наследуются классы справочников `Goods` товары, `Units` единицы измерения. В суперклассе определен метод `creationString()`

```
public String creationString() {
    String creationString = super.creationString();
    creationString += COL_NAME + " TEXT);";
    return creationString;
}
```

метод нужен для формирования строки создания таблицы [sqlite](/questions/tagged/sqlite) базы данных. Класс `Catalog` наследуется от еще более абстрактного класса `Table` в котором `creationString` начинается со слов `CREATE TABLE` и т.д.

В классе `Catalog` метод `creationString()` перегружается 2 раза

```
public String creationString(boolean hasIerarchy) {
    String creationString = this.creationString();
    if (hasIerarchy) {
        creationString = trimEndCreationString(creationString);
        creationString += ", "+COL_PARENT+" INTEGER"
                        +", "+COL_ISFOLDER+" NUMERIC);";
    }
    return creationString;
}
```

и

```
    public String creationString(boolean hasIerarchy, boolean hasOwner) {
    String creationString = this.creationString(hasIerarchy);
    if (hasOwner) {
        creationString = trimEndCreationString(creationString);
        creationString += ", "+COL_OWNER+" INTEGER);";
    }
    return creationString;
}
```

То есть в перегруженных вызовах вызывается предыдущая версия метода с меньшим количеством агрументов, чтобы добавить к строке создания новые поля.
В классе `Goods` - метод `creationString()` - переопределяется.

```
public String creationString() {
    String creationString = super.creationString(true);
    creationString = trimEndCreationString(creationString);
    creationString += ", " + COL_FNAME + " TEXT, "
            + COL_ART + " TEXT, "
            + COL_BASE_UNIT + " INTEGER, "
            + COL_TYPE + " INTEGER);";
    return creationString;
}
```

В этом методе вызывается версия метода суперкласса с одним булевым аргументом, чтобы добавить колонку родителя.

Проблема в том, что когда в этом методе суперкласса вызывается  `creationString()` без агрументов - вызывается переопределнный `creationString()` из класса `Goods` И я получаю ошибку `StackOverFrow` Как в таком случае четко определить чтобы вызывался `creationString()` из конкретного класса, а не переопределенная версия?

Answer (score 0):

Класс `Catalog` не переопределяет метод родителя, а создает новый перегруженный метод, так как для `overriding` есть определенные правила и одно из них это неизменность сигнатуры метода, в которую входят параметры метода. Вот Ваш класс `Goods` переопределяет метод супер-предка класса**`Table`**, а не методы `Catalog`.

Поэтому когда у объекта класса `Goods` который хранится в переменной типа `Table`, происходит вызов метода createTable(), то согласно полиморфизму и динамическому связыванию вызывается переопределенный метод класса `Goods`.

Дальше, из этого метода вызывается, метод класса `Catalog` и в нем идет вызов метода родителя `this.creationString()`, но опять срабатывает полиморфизм и вызывается метод класса `Goods`. Начинается бесконечный цикл который приводит к `StackOverFlowError`

Чтобы решить эту проблемму, можно в классе `Catalog` сменить `this.creationString()` на `super.creationString()` тогда явно вызовется метод класса `Table`.

У Вас явные проблеммы с архитектурой и ее надо пересмотреть. Потому как предложенное мной решение лишь усугубит дальнейшие проблемы.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но ваше предложение вызвать в `Catalog` метод `super.creationString()` - не решает проблему, так как реализация метода в классе `Table` не подходит, нужна именно реализация в текущем классе `Catalog`. Интуитивно я понимаю, что нужно кое-где разорвать цепочку переопределений и назвать методы  по другому. Буду пробовать.

Comment: @ДмитрийКасминюк Можно уточнить - делая вызов `this.creationString()` в методе класса `Catalog` вы какой метод хотите вызвать? У вас все очень двусмысленно написано

Answer (score 0):

Возможно я действительно неточно выразился. Метод  `creationString()` есть во всех 3-х классах `Table` `Catalog` `Goods`. Соответственно все они друг друга переопределяют. Соответственно когда я в классе `Catalog` пишу `this.creationString()`, то ожидаю вызов метода описанного в классе `Catalog`. Но я уже разобрался с этой проблемой. Сделал практически так, как вы советовали. Удалил метод `creationString()` из класса `Catalog`, а код, который был в нем поместил в метод `creationString(boolean hasIerarchy)`. Соответствено теперь я переопределяю в классе `Goods` метод `creationString()` сразу из класса `Table`, хотя и вызываю другой метод суперкласса не связанный с переопределением.